# Python 3.5 returning unexpected answer

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an unexpected outcome in python. The output should be 440, but I get 370 so I am missing something in my loop I think.

The code is calculating fixed payments to pay off a balance (`b`) taking into account interest (`mir`) and increasing payment (`mp`) by 10 each loop if the balance isn't paid off.

My current code is

```
b = 4773
air = 0.2


mir = air/12.0
m = 1
mp = 10


while m in range(0,12):

    ub = b - mp
    b = ub + (mir * ub) 
    cb = b
    m += 1
    if cb> 0: 
       mp += 10
       m = 0

print(str(mp))
```

I am not looking for so much a code fix, but an explanation of where I am going wrong and what I should look at to fix it. I can see the code running and it loops fine I am just ending up with an unexpected answer so I am missing something. I am trying to learn python and that would help me more than just a fix :)

Comment: In Python indentation is a part of syntax. Please verify that presented code snippet has appropriately indented blocks. Lines below `if cb> 0:` smells particularly suspicious.

Comment: It would help other people understand your code an *enormous* amount if you used names that had obvious meanings. I'm guessing this is some kind of compound interest calculator, but a lot of the variables are completely opaque to me, so I have no idea why you're doing the calculations you are doing.

Comment: The indentation of your if-statement is off.  At least the next line should be indented one more level.

Comment: May be because of floating point rounding off error.

Comment: What is the code supposed to actually be doing?

Comment: `cb` is just an alias for `b`.  You could get rid of `cb`.

Comment: I fixed the error in indentation in the post. I had copied it wrong.  The formula is calculating fixed payments to pay off a balance taking into account interest and increasing payment by 10 each loop if the balance isn't paid off.

Comment: Why are you resetting `m` in the `if` block, and why do you keep looping until `m` is `12` after balance finally goes negative? There's a lot of stuff that doesn't make any sense in the code, and without a clear explanation of what you're trying to accomplish and what the "rules" you're simulating are, there's no possible way for us to know what your errors are.

Comment: Do `print(b, ub, m, mp)` as the last line of your loop and see where your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Also, you should break out of your loop if the balance is negative.

Comment: You might want to use `while 0<=m<=11` rather than  `while m in range(0,12)`

Comment: Thank you for all the replies! I am working on implementing them and might see where I went wrong. How do I upvote answers? Sorry I am new to all this and will likely be asking some more dumb questions, but I appreciate all answers!

Comment: Why keep track of `m`?  Shouldn't your loop control just by `while b > 0:`?  Regarding upvoting, these are comments, not answers.

Comment: @answrseeker just click the arrow above the flag to the left of this comment and see the magic, Try it out on this comment first.

Comment: Is this from the EDX 6.01x course, is that why the variable names are so cryptic?

Comment: It is for course which is why I am not posting the problem or asking for the answer just direction on where I messed up like the program rules state you can. I kept them short because in my frustration I kept making spelling errors which compounded my frustration so I made them single letters until I could grasp what I was doing wrong without misspelling things when I changed them around.

Comment: Were you able to fix the error? If so what was it?

Comment: I was able to fix it by just trashing my code and going with a for loop instead of an if loop as the inner loop. I was trying to fine tune the if statement and would get close, but would mess up something else. One of my friends who is a coder for a living told me to try starting over as that is the hard lesson of coding. Often to move forward you have to trash it and begin again when you are stuck deep in a code changing things left and right. She was right!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in the comments:

> The formula is calculating fixed payments to pay off a balance taking into account interest and increasing payment by 10 each loop if the balance isn't paid off.

I would do the following.  (I tried to give your variables descriptive names.)

```
balance = 4773
annual_interest_rate = 0.2
monthly_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate / 12
number_of_payments = 0
payment = 10

while balance > 0:
    number_of_payments += 1
    balance -= payment
    balance += balance * monthly_interest_rate
    print(number_of_payments, payment, balance)
    payment += 10
```

This outputs:

```
1 10 4842.38333333
2 20 4902.75638889
3 30 4953.96899537
4 40 4995.86847863
5 50 5028.29961994
6 60 5051.1046136
7 70 5064.12302383
8 80 5067.19174089
9 90 5060.14493657
10 100 5042.81401885
11 110 5015.02758583
12 120 4976.61137893
13 130 4927.38823524
14 140 4867.17803917
15 150 4795.79767315
16 160 4713.0609677
17 170 4618.7786505
18 180 4512.75829467
19 190 4394.80426625
20 200 4264.71767069
21 210 4122.29629853
22 220 3967.33457018
23 230 3799.62347968
24 240 3618.95053767
25 250 3425.0997133
26 260 3217.85137519
27 270 2996.98223144
28 280 2762.26526863
29 290 2513.46968978
30 300 2250.36085127
31 310 1972.7001988
32 320 1680.24520211
33 330 1372.74928881
34 340 1049.96177696
35 350 711.627806573
36 360 357.488270016
37 370 -12.7202588168
```

Comment: Adding the printing helps a lot. I am going to start over and give this another go. I am new to python so I have lots of trial and error right now!